# EXCEL SUMIFS to nth value and return position

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have a large spreadsheet with incoming quantities on it that i need to extract data from.
On the Y axis is our item SKU, and on the X is the Purchase Order in which the item came in on. I want to be able to take my current quantity and count from either left or right (right preferred) and return the current purchase orders my quantities are from.

Example: If i have 122 of one item, and we've brought in 352 over the last 7 orders, i would like to return which previous orders my remaining product is from.

Once i am able to return the orders in which my remaining quantities are from, i can index match the corresponding cost on the COST tab (which is laid out the same way) and calculate my FIFO (first in, first out) costing.

[image]
Also, i really dont know how to add any other information in to help you guys with what im working with.

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the added picture. The red arrow is the part i would like automated. It returns the current Purchase order in which a pulled item would originate from.
basically just count from the right and stop once the SUM is within the range of the current quantity.
[image]

Comment: Please provide an example output for one set of inputs based on the provided sample data.

Comment: Show us what you have done to try to solve your problem, and specifically where you have gotten error messages or incorrect answers.

Comment: Does the field name have a date or some way to identify the order?

Comment: I added in what i wanted. I havent found any formulas that remotely work and just give a #value error, otherwise i could share were i started. And the order is preset at the time of purchase. I have a macro that builds this database.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Function that would work if this is always going to be the format of your table:

```
Function GetInventoryPO(Current_Quantity As Long, Inventory_List As Variant) As String

    Dim i As Long, x As Long, InvtyArr As Variant

    InvtyArr = Inventory_List
    For x = UBound(InvtyArr, 2) To 1 Step -1
        If InvtyArr(1, x) <> Empty Then i = i + InvtyArr(1, x)
        If Current_Quantity < i Then Exit For
    Next x

    GetInventoryPO = Cells(1, x + 1).Value

End Function
```

It should look like this in Excel:

[image]

However, feel free to just integrate the code to your existing macros.

Comment: I'm trying this now. It's giving me the #NAME? error

Comment: I got the function to work, but it's inconsistent. It's not returning the correct purchase order for about 30% of the lines.